# Multistep registration form for two roles

Tags: 7, forms, users

Goal:

I have two different user roles:

1. Borrower
2. Provider

There are 5 categories for these users to choose(they can select all if they want):

1. Market 1
2. Market 2
3. Market 3
4. Market 4
5. Market 5

Each roles have different registration forms depending on the categories they picked. Let say:

For Borrower role:

```
If Market 1:
  step one: 
    form A
  step two:
    form B:

If Market 2-5:
  step one: 
    form A:
  step two:
    form C:
```

For Provider role:

```
If Market 1-4:
  step one:
    form A:
  step two:
    form D:


If Market 5:
  step one: 
    form A:
  step two:
    form E:


Where:
  form A = generic registration form
  form B = specific for Borrower role selecting Market 1
  form C = generic form for Borrower role selecting Market 2 to 5
  form D = generic form for Provider role selecting Market 1 to 4
  form E = specific form for Provider role selecting Market 5
```

Question:
  Is there any module that can do this? Any thoughts how can I achieve this using Drupal API's?

Comment: +1 for this question...I would like to see other best approach in this kind of problem

Answer (score 2):

These modules might help you:

- [Profile2](http://drupal.org/project/profile2) for creating different user profiles based on role
- [Profile2 registration path](http://drupal.org/project/profile2_regpath) to have separate registration pages
- [Formflow](http://drupal.org/project/formflow) to connect multiple forms in a single "workflow"

Comment: Thanks Ivanhoel123 I already installed these modules and already setup diff roles but still I'm in the middle of nowhere. Is it possible to add custom/new fields in Profile2?

Comment: This was more of a starting point on a first glance :) What do you mean by adding custom/new fields in profile2?

Comment: IN `admin/structure/profiles` for each profile types there is an option to add new fields in the manage fields. Is it ok to add new fields there or create a seperate form using FormAPI?